Choice of Ammonia and oxygen as liquid rocket propellants in vortex combustion
I have been thinking lately about the benefits of using liquid ammonia and oxygen as rocket propellants, where ammonia is difficult to burn, what if in a fuel rich closed cycle, ammonia is used to cool the nozzle then it is easily decomposed in the preburner before entering the combustion chamber. Then oxygen is injected along the walls of the combustion chamber to achieve vortex combustion, wouldn't improve the performance?
Please note I'm not a rocket scientist just an enthusiast

Early rocket engines like the XLR series used in the X-15 research airplane used these propellants. There is a schematic of the engine in this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22760/6944

Ammonia combustion in oxygen has the chemical reaction:
4NH3 + 3O2 → 2N2 + 6H2O
The enthalpy of the reaction is -1531 kJ/mol (of reactants as specified), which is of the order of other rocket fuels. So in principle it can work, but I don't know the details. @OrganicMarble 's link is a great place to start.
It's a great question. Given the X-15 used it at one stage I wonder why it was abandoned.

It would be no better than a Hydrolox engine (or infact worse) for 2 major points: 1. The Hydrogen may leak. 2. The nitrogen will reduce combustion and Isp.

also potentially of interest; answers to What kind of engine does this Isp = 1600 refer to? Is it cubesat-friendly?

It would work only if it the nitrogen would combust. Here's my explanation:
Ammonia is NH4, meaning each molecule has 1 nitrogen and 4 hydrogen atoms. When it decomposes, it will become Hydrogen and nitrogen. The hydrogen is the main point. It will not be simpler than a Hydrolox engine, and also need extra oxidizer to oxidize the nitrogen. This means, the fuel rich cycle would need to be as close to sociometric as possible to oxidize all the nitrogen and some of the hydrogen. Of which Nitrogen has less energy density than Hydrogen.
Here's the equation:
NH4 + 2O2 --combustion--> 2H2O + N2O.
This is incredibly inefficient and since the engine would already need to be as complex as a Hydrolox engine to deal with gaseous hydrogen, and also need extra Oxidizer to oxidize the incombustable nitrogen, it would be no different from trying to reduce efficiency (and Isp) by injecting nitrogen into a fuel rich Hydrolox engine. Which is unnecessary.
Part 2: (less important, for some who still think it is a good idea)
Ammonia decomposed would not be hypergolic, and the ammonia itself would still need to be stored cold at -33.34°C and also need a igniter to combust. So, why not use Hydrazine and Nitrogen tetroxide instead. It is more efficient and hypergolic. Also, easier to handle engine.
(Feel free to edit if necessary)

Your first sentence sounds like you're saying such an engine won't work. However, these engines have flown in the X-15.
